# What does the last scene in Woman In Black imply?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-woman-in-black

Assuming that the curse of the Woman In Black is over, the movie ends with the Woman In Black appearing again. Did this mean that the Woman In Black will still haunt the Edwardian era English village?

Comment: I also remember in the end the Woman in Black saying "I will never forgive you, never forgive you..." repeatedly. I kind of realized at that point that she is never going to let the village live in peace and hence even after Kipps found her son's body and buried it, she still went on killing Kipps's son..

Answer (score 4):

Yes, we are to assume that the woman will still haunt the house.

This of course enable us to see [The Woman In Black 2: Angel of Death](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2339741/).

Answer (score 2):

She looks sadly at the now-dead family reunited and going on to heaven, indicating a longing to be at peace. However, her intense hatred keeps her from being at peace and as such, she will continue to haunt the village for the foreseeable future. Hence, we were given a sequel.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since i saw the movie, This is what i remember they try to lift the curse by burying the body of Jennet's son who was still left in marshes and doing so they assume that curse might be lifted but as we know later at the end of the movie it was a wrong assumption and as evidenced by the final scene the curse still isn't broken and we are left to assume that she is still in large haunting the village.

Answer (score 1):

I thought the ending implied after the main character reunited her with her son she returned the favor and reunited them with the mother.  The father and son seemed happy at the end which to me implied that life on Earth caused too much pain without his lost love and the child's mother.